# Hide/Show Multiple Divs in one script

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I am a JS noob and am trying to code something for my website. I want to hide/show divs onclick, which I have been able to do without any issues, but once I want to do it again I have to replicate the script for every div i want to hide... Can somebody help me fix this script so that I only need to have it once? Maybe using a variable or something? I am really new to JS and would really appreciate the help!

Here is an example of the script:

```
<script>
    function hideShowDiv1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hideShowDiv1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: why not pass in the div name to your function

Answer (score 0):

Use classes not id's - because in HTML can be only one element with same ID but many elements with same class. Here simple example of working code.

HTML:

```
<div class="a">Test 1</div>
<div class="a">Test 2</div>
```

Javascript:

```
const toggle = () => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('a')).forEach(e => {
    console.log('e', e.style.display, (e.style.display === 'none'))
    e.style.display = (e.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none'
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your elements your are trying to access look like.
You can for exemple add common class to it and query them based on this class name

```
const allElements = document.querySelectorAll(".commonClassName");

allElements.forEach(element => {
  element.style.display = (element.style.display === "none")
    ? "block"
    : "none"
})
```

You can find more exemples using `querySelectorAll` on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use css classes for that.

You can directly run the snippet below:

```js
function toggleVisibility(e) {
  const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
  targets.forEach(target => {
    if (target.style.display === 'none') {
      target.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      target.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle" onclick="toggleVisibility()">Toggle</button>

<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty with this as a newbie. I was using bootstrap for a WP site and found the code I need in Bootstrap which looked like this. I found this did what I needed.

This for each button:

```
Button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle_xanadu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="toggle_xanadu">More.../Button
```

This to display the content:

```
div class="list_div collapse" id="toggle_xanadu">Content</div>
```

Simple but read more on the Bootstrap site for more options.

I am looking at a database and PHP for this in the long term.